# How to validate the location of an element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Got the location of an element, but don't know how to validate it

I assumed the ExpectedValue as (0, 0)

WebElement element = common.getElement(object);
Point ActualValue = element.getLocation();

How to compare these ActualValue and the ExpectedValue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use JUnit for validation:

```
final WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.id("id"));
final Point location = element.getLocation();
final int x = location.getX();
final int y = location.getY();
assertThat(x, is(0));
assertThat(y, is(0));
```

Comment: By this we will get individual values of x n y.    I want to compare the (x,y) positions of location with the ExpectedValue

Comment: I tried comparing using the if case.  If (ActualValue.equals(ExpectedValue)){   print values are equal.  }